# Stay on a Winform dialog box and display message with user errors

Tags: c#, modal-dialog

I have a dialog box that I display over my main form (not an MDI)

I call it this way:

```
dlgPets dlgPet = new dlgPets();
dlgPet.Show();
```

Once on the dialog, the user will click a button and that is where i verify what was entered.  If it fails, I just return

What happens is the dialog box goes away.

I have also tried adding:

```
Dialog result = dlgPet.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    return;
}
```

I need to stay on the dlgPet dialog box until the user clicks the cancel button.

Thanks in advance
Mark

Comment: Can you show us the dialog implementation and especially the click event handling in the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should use
`dlgPet.TopMost = true;`

Comment: I put that right before the .Show(), no change.  It still leaves the dialog.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I changed it to Show(); and it works as expected but i had to Alt-Tab to find it.  I left the TopLevel = true.  That didn't work so I changed that to TopMost = true and that did the trick.  Thanks for sending me in the right direction.

Comment: Ok, try it. 
dlgPet.ShowDialog();

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you want to stop at dialog form whenever the error is shown then you need to handle form closing event where you can say whether to proceed with closing of form or not by using form closing event args.
e.g. e.Cancel = true will cancel out form closing event meaning form will not be closed.[code image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3BGN.png)[code image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahbl9.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.